# Diferencia entre dos consultas MYSQL a la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, conjuntos

Tengo esta consulta que me devuele los Creyentes que hicieron una donacion en un rango de fechas

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Creyente.id_creyente), Creyente.nombre, Creyente.apellido, Creyente.direccion, Creyente.correo, Creyente.celular 
       FROM Creyente,
            Donacion,
            SobreCreyente 
       WHERE Creyente.id_creyente = SobreCreyente.id_creyente 
             AND SobreCreyente.numero = Donacion.sobre 
             and Donacion.fecha BETWEEN '2019-06-15' AND '2019-06-18'
```

y Tengo esta consulta que me devuelve todos los creyentes de la base de datos

```
SELECT Creyente.id_creyente, Creyente.nombre, Creyente.apellido, Creyente.direccion, Creyente.correo, Creyente.celular 
       FROM Creyente
```

la primera me daria algo asi

```
-------------------------------
id -  nombre - apellido
-------------------------------
1 -  creyente1 - creyente1
2 -  creyente2 - creyente2
-------------------------------
```

y la segunda consulta me daria todos los creyentes tipo:

```
-------------------------------
id -  nombre - apellido
-------------------------------
1 -  creyente1 - creyente1
2 -  creyente2 - creyente2
3 -  creyente3 - creyente3
4 -  creyente4 - creyente4
-------------------------------
```

Necesito obtener la diferencia entre estas dos consultas, osea:

```
-------------------------------
id -  nombre - apellido
-------------------------------
3 -  creyente3 - creyente3
4 -  creyente4 - creyente4
-------------------------------
```

¿Alguien sabe como podría obtener este resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un `NOT IN`

```
SELECT Creyente.id_creyente, Creyente.nombre, Creyente.apellido, Creyente.direccion, Creyente.correo, Creyente.celular 
FROM Creyente 
WHERE Creyente.id_creyente 
      NOT IN (
           SELECT DISTINCT (Creyente.id_creyente) 
           FROM Creyente,Donacion,SobreCreyente 
           WHERE Creyente.id_creyente = SobreCreyente.id_creyente 
           AND SobreCreyente.numero = Donacion.sobre 
           AND Donacion.fecha BETWEEN '2019-06-15' AND '2019-06-18'
      )
```